# Appending an if else list into a matrix or another container such as a dataframe. Sorting and printing into matrix with loop

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, printing, append

Suppose we had the code and wanted to output the print into a matrix, dataframe, vector or list. Let's just

```
library(quantmod)    
StockList <- c("AAIT", "AAL",  "AAME", "AAOI", "AAON", "AAPC", "AAPL", "AAVL", "AAWW", "AAXJ")
s<-10
for (i in 1:length(StockList)){print(i)
get_fin<-tryCatch(lapply(StockList[i], function(x) getFinancials(x, auto.assign = FALSE)), error=function(e) NULL)                          
if(!is.null(get_fin)){
Keep<-print("Keep") 
}
else {Delete<-print("Delete")}}
```

Transform this output into a structured matrix:

```
[1] 1
[1] "Delete"
[1] 2
[1] "Keep"
[1] 3
[1] "Keep"
[1] 4
[1] "Keep"
[1] 5
[1] "Keep"
[1] 6
[1] "Delete"
[1] 7
[1] "Keep"
[1] 8
[1] "Keep"
[1] 9
[1] "Keep"
[1] 10
[1] "Keep"
```

The output below is what I wish to have:

```
    [1,]
[1,]"Delete"
[2,]"Keep"
[3,]"Keep"
[4,]"Keep"
[5,]"Keep"
[6,]"Delete"
[7,]"Keep"
[8,]"Keep"
[9,]"Keep"
[10,]"Keep"
```

Above is the matrix that I wish to have. I wrote it out manually. If you can help, thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, @plafort and all the code is off. I meant to put in a reproducible example. Here it should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a vector to hold the results and changing the if statement to assign the output:

```
    StockList <- c("AAIT", "AAL",  "AAME", "AAOI", "AAON", "AAPC", "AAPL", "AAVL", "AAWW", "AAXJ")
 s<-10
 result <- c()
 for (i in 1:length(StockList)){print(i)
   get_fin<-tryCatch(lapply(StockList[i], function(x) getFinancials(x, auto.assign = FALSE)), error=function(e) NULL)                          
   if(!is.null(get_fin)){
     result[i] <- "Keep" 
   }
   else {result[i] <- "Delete"}}
 matrix(result, ncol=1)
```

Comment: I love the idea. I get this output though `[,1]  
 [1,] NA    
 [2,] NA    
 [3,] NA    
 [4,] NA    
 [5,] NA    
 [6,] NA    
 [7,] NA    
 [8,] NA    
 [9,] NA    
[10,] "Keep"`